# unable to decode image64 encoded data on server side passed from ios application

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

found several ways to encode data in image64 bit format

Correct way to encode data in image64 format

unable to decode image64 bit data received on server side, while encoded data can easily decode before passing on server.

and encoded data received from android application is what same of encoded data send from ios platform can decode on server

**code used to encode data**

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.01);

[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
imageData =  [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.01) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
```

**code used to submit data on server**

```
servicesManager = manager;
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest
                                 requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                 urlParam]
                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                 timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSString *post = [self createQueryStringForDataDictionary:dataDictionaryParam];

self.urlTo = urlParam;
NSLog(@"post data : %@",post);

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (con) {
    _receivedData=[NSMutableData data];
} else {
    //something bad happened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this part of code to encode image64

```
UIImage *encodeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userImage.png"];
NSString *stringImg =  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(encodeImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

This encoded string can be sent to server

and used this code to decode that image in iamge64

```
NSData *imgdata = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:stringImg options:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
UIImage *decodeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];
```

It works for me try this it will work for you also